# How to enable KMS encryption for AWS ECR when using CloudFormation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr, elastic-container-registry

Reading the AWS documentation regarding ECR CloudFormation template:

[See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecr-repository.html#aws-resource-ecr-repository-properties).

I've not been able to find how to specify the encryption at rest you want. I know by default it uses AES-256. But I want to be able to specify KMS. In simple terms my template looks like this:

```
Resources:
    logicalid:
        Type: 'AWS::ECR::Repository'
        Properties:
            RepositoryName : "repo-name"
            ImageScanningConfiguration:
                scanOnPush: "true"
            ImageTagMutability: "IMMUTABLE"
            EncryptionConfiguration:
                 encryptionType:"KMS"
```

But EncryptionConfiguration is not a valid option. I assume there must be a way given that the SDK's  allow you to specify it:

[See here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_EncryptionConfiguration.html#:%7E:text=EncryptionConfiguration.%20The%20encryption%20configuration%20for%20the%20repository.%20This,data%20at%20rest%20using%20an%20AES-256%20encryption%20algorithm.)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not supported yet**. KMS encryption for ECR is rather [new](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/07/ecr-supports-encryption-images-aws-kms-keys/) and CloudFormation does not have this option yet.

The only way would be to create your ECR repo using [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) in CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

AWS cloud formation now supports an option to specify KMS to have encryption at rest.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/771

Comment: Could you please add a link to the official docs/blog post on this, for reference?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecr-repository-encryptionconfiguration.html I hope this is what you were looking for